# C#: WPF MultiValueConverter checking object[] to null

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

Now I'm working with WPF and creating custom MessageControl. 
Message Control has 2 properties:
1. string Detail
 
2. string Solution
I have VisibilityConverter that implements `IMultiValueConverter`, and in `Convert` method i need to check the Detail and Solution. if Detail or Solution is not `null`, not `string.Empty` or not `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` I need to return `Visibility.Visible`. The problem is `values` in converter parameter is `object[]`. if I do `values[0].ToString()` and when `values[0]` is null throws exception here.Now my code is works but it is many lines of code. My variant here:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //if Detail or Solution is not null,not empty and not UnsetValue than show control
            if (values[0] != null && values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                if (values[0].ToString() != string.Empty)
                {
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }

            if (values[1] != null && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                if (values[1].ToString() != string.Empty)
                {
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

Is there best way to check it with minimum line of code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (try it, I didn't):

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Any(v => v == null || v == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.ToString()))) return Visibility.Collapsed;
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks for idea it works for me!

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //if Detail or Solution is not null,not empty and not UnsetValue than show control 
            if (values.Any(v => v is string && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.ToString()))) return Visibility.Visible;
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```